# How to parallelize a for loop in python with mpi4py which needs to output an array of numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, mpi4py

I have a for loop which calculates a number in each iteration and sets it as a new element in a zeros array. How to parallelize this loop with mpi4py? Help is much appreciated! Code is given below.

```
    b = 1000
    R = numpy.linspace(2, 2.5, b)
    z = numpy.zeros_like(R)
    for i in range(len(z)):
        z[i] = calculate(R[i]) #pseudocode
```

There is some example of parallelizing a for loop which adds numbers on this website ([https://computationalmechanics.in/parallelizing-for-loop-in-python-with-mpi/]), but I don't even know how to begin! (Beside the part on the beggining which I understand, setting the rank, size, etc).

Comment: Why `mpi4py` in particular? I'd start with seeing if you can `numba.jit` the `calculate` function, and if it's not fast enough then, try e.g. plain old `multiprocessing`.

Comment: As an aside: `z = [calculate(x) for x in numpy.linspace(2, 2.5, b)]` would be more succinct...

Comment: I guess that works too, though even multiprocessing is abstract and not understandable to me.
Also, there is no single calculate function, that actually represents like 5 separate functions and like 100 lines of code but agreed, that's more succinct.